# Center a DIV containing relative element using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I struggle about this behavior. I add two DIVs (sub1 and sub2) inside a DIV container. Sub2 is set a relative position to overlap the bottom right corner of the Sub1. Doing this, the width of the container DIV isn't good, it is the same as before changing relative position of Sub1. At first, it wasn't problematic, but then, the client decided to center the whole thing, thus needing the real width of the container.

Can this be achieved via CSS ? Even in JavaScript, I got the same width (the erronus one).

Here is the a simple example of the problem :

```css
html, body {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#main {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}

#sub1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:red;
  position: relative;
}

#sub2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  left: 80px;
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div id="sub1">
</div>
<div id="sub2">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your container DIV to possess width of two blocks you shouldn't use relative positioning. Use margin instead

```
#sub2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a little unclear of what behavior you want to see. I take it you want the red and blue squares to overlap, but you also want them to be centered in the page? In that case the solution is easy, just add another DIV layer between "main" and the smaller boxes.

```css
html, body {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#main {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#sub1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color:red;
  position: relative;
}

#sub2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  left: 80px;
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="center">
        <div id="sub1">
        </div>
        <div id="sub2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Generally for each "transformation" that you want an element to do, you should add another DIV wrapper around it for that transformation. That way each transform is independent from one another and they're easier to manage.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a popular way to center any element (without adding more divs): use the `transform` property in conjunction with `left` (or `top` for vertical centering).

```css
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#main {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#sub1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:red;
    position: relative;
}

#sub2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    left: 80px;
    top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="sub1"></div>
    <div id="sub2"></div>
</div>
```

I also removed `display: inline-block;` from `#main{}` because it wasn't doing anything in this demo.

Comment: This is about what I'm searching for. The problem I'd like to fix too is not hardcoding the width of "main". Though, without it, a problem happen in positionning due to not correct "main's width". Can it be done ?

Comment: @MasterDJon There are a couple ways, but looks like vedmaque's solution solves your problem already! :-)

Comment: Well, in fact I used a conjonction of all your solutions. Though, because I can only accept one solution, I preferred the one solving the primary problem and the person having the lowest reputation (to help her/him grow).

Comment: @MasterDJon No worries. Though you should always pick the best answer to your solution as the accepted answer, regardless of the answerer's reputation! The accepted answer literally means "this solved my problem [best]".